# In unix, how can I pipe the output of who into the groups command?

Tags: shell, unix, usergroups

I'm trying to do something like this:

Say there are 4 users logged into a UNIX machine, a, b, c, and d.

Now, to get the groups these guys belong to, I have to type out :

```
groups a b c d.
```

What I am wondering, is if there is a way to do something like `who | groups` where I can pipe the users currently logged-in to the groups command, which would then print out all the users given along with their group information. However, this does not seem to work as intended - rather, the above command just gives the group the first user belongs to.

Answer (score 2):

In bash, zsh, and others:

```
groups $(who | cut -d' ' -f 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Though I have not checked this one:

```
who -q | xargs -o groups
```

But you should be able to use xargs for this

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs

Comment: I love xargs!  The best part of this solution (compared to backticks or a $() command) is that it allows the logical flow of the command to remain left-to-right

Answer (score 0):

```
groups $(who -q)|head -n -1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
who | while read -r user line; do echo "$user $line" -- `groups $user`; done
```

This will output the "who" command with the  groups on the side